# Finding matching values in several dataframes

Tags: r

I have been using previous questions asked in this forum to answer my question but I keep having error messages.

Very simple scenario but I am new to R and cannot manage to understand why I have all those error messages.

I have three different dataframes df1, df2, df3, each with only one column (and about 200 rows). I only want to identify which values are common to the three dataframes.

I have already tried the inner_join function of dplyr but I keep having error messages about 'by' being required... but even with the R help, cannot figure what it means and how to change it.

I have found a similar query in this forum but nothing I try works.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please read [how to ask a reproducible example in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [edit] your question. We need input to figure out why you are getting errors from previous solutions.

Comment: `Reduce(function(x,y)merge(list(x=x[,1]),list(x=y[,1])),list(df1,df2,df3))`

Comment: `data.frame(Reduce(intersect,list(df1[,1],df2[,1],df3[,1])))`